# Fetch TextField value by pressing Jbutton

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

Here is the problem:

I want an interactive GUI that has a `TextField` and a `JButton`. Users enter their `pincode` in `TextField`, press the `JButton` and the value fetches from main class to use as an argument in a function.

This is my JFrame with TextField and Button code:

```
    public class JTextFieldDemo extends JFrame {

    //Class Declarations
    JTextField jtfText1, jtfUneditableText;
    String disp = "";
    ButtonHandler handler = null;
    String pin;
    //Constructor
    public JTextFieldDemo() {
        super("Smart Token Utility");
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jtfText1 = new JTextField(10);
        jtfUneditableText = new JTextField("Please Enter Your PIN Code", 20);
        jtfUneditableText.setEditable(false);
        container.add(jtfText1);
        container.add(jtfUneditableText);
        handler = new ButtonHandler();


        JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
        button.setSize(3,5);
        button.addActionListener(handler);
        container.add(button);
        setSize(325, 100);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        jtfText1.addActionListener(handler);

    }
    //Inner Class ButtonHandler
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             pin = jtfText1.getText();

        }
    }
```

and This is my main class code:

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
        JTextFieldDemo test = new JTextFieldDemo();
        String pincode = test.pin;
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        KeyStore.load(null, pincode);
    }
```

I have two problems:

1) When I run the main class, the `Jframe` appears and before I can type anything in `TextField` it disappears.

2) The `pincode` in the main class is always `null` even if I hardcoded it in `ButtonHandler` class.

Answer (score -1):

As your main method get the pin code after creation of the JFrame, it will have the default value-null. So Getting the pin code(KeyStore.load(null, pincode))  method should be in ButtonHandler#actionPerformed().

But in your case you can use `JOptionPane#showInputDialog(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)` to get the input.

Comment: Well, this is not exactly the answer for this question, but in my case solve the problem. So +1 for your help and thank you.